# Function in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I am very new in programming and I have been given the task to translate a script from vb into c#. I have the following line of code which, for as much as I can google it, I can't make sense of it:

*aim_tonnes = dailyRecords.Where(Function(record) record.dt_start.Hour = 0).Sum(Function(record) record.ms_aim_production)*

I do understand the meaning of it but what I struggle with is *Function(record)* as I can't find it declared anywhere in the original script and I don't understand what it does. Is anyone able to give me some directions? Thanks a lot, really appreciated!

Comment: Use https://converter.telerik.com/ to convert your code.

Answer (score 1):

That's a lambda expression.

```vb
Function(record) record.dt_start.Hour = 0
```

would translate to:

```cs
record => record.dt_start.Hour == 0
```